# Print in an array for list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does Print have to be in an array

This code is failing vs the one below:

`print(num) for num in [1,2,3,4]`

the one that works:

`[print(num) for num in [1,2,3,4]]`

Why does the first one fail?

Answer (score 1):

This one `[print(num) for num in [1,2,3,4]]`, is a comprehension , exactly a **list** comprehension that builds a list upon an expresion, and you should not use it, because `print` returns `None` in each call so you are building a list for nothing.

The other is completly invalid python sintax `print(num) for num in [1,2,3,4]`, the correct sintax is:

```
for num in [1,2,3,4]:
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

First example fails since it has a syntax error, it will only work for a normal for loop like so

```
for num in [1,2,3,4]:
    print(num)
```

For list comprehension, your expression has to be enclosed under `[` and `]` like the second example

```
[print(num) for num in [1,2,3,4]]
```

Also make a note that list comprehension is a bad choice for function which do not return a value, like `print` since by doing this, you are creating an array on `None`.

```
li = [print(num) for num in [1,2,3,4]]
#1
#2
#3
#4
print(li)
#[None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(num) for num in [1,2,3,4]` has incorrect syntax.

If you do **not** use list comprehension, then iterating through a list should be done with a loop, which has the following syntax:

```
for num in [1,2,3,4]:
    print(num)
```

In essence, list comprehensions are special syntactic tools in Python, and not a variety of regular code presentation.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is for general information only and does not suggest to actually use a generator or comprehension for such a straightforward task**

The first one fails because it is not a valid syntax.

If you will surround it with parenthesis it will become a generator:

```
g = (print(num) for num in [1, 2, 3, 4])
print(g)
# <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000025F231C8408>
```

However notice that nothing is printed because generators are lazy. They are not evaluated until it is totally necessary.

One way to evaluate `g` in this case will be to pass it to `list`:

```
print(list(g))
#  1
#  2
#  3
#  4
#  [None, None, None, None]
```

Note that this is wasteful. `print` returns `None` so we are actually building a list for nothing.

Instead of building the list you could use `next`:

```
g = (print(num) for num in [1, 2, 3, 4])

while True:
    try:
        next(g)
    except StopIteration:
        break
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
```

But do not do this. All of these "solutions" abuse more sophisticated mechanics of the language just to print a list of numbers. Simply go with the explicit `for` loop suggested in other answers.